# JQuery failing on getting value of textarea

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, textarea

I know this is a common question, and I tried all found solutions.

Anyway, nothing seems working.

I tried getting the value with `val()`, `text()` and `html()` also, as someone suggested: NOTHING!

Here's my HTML (we're in Wordpress):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
        <?php _e( 'Content:', 'helpy'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="nine columns">
        <textarea id="new_task_content" class="helpy-textarea" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Place the content here...', 'helpy'); ?>"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
        <?php _e( 'Due date:', 'helpy'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="nine columns">
        <input type="date" id="new_task_due" class="helpy-date-input" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <button type="button" id="new_task" class="button-helpy"><?php _e( 'Confirm', 'helpy'); ?></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$('#new_task').live('click', function() {
    var task_due = $('#new_task_due').val();
    var task_content = $('#new_task_content').val();
    console.log(task_content);
    console.log(task_due);
    /* var data = {
        action: 'project_request',
        task_content: task_content,
        task_due: task_due,
        id: '<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>',
        todo: 'task',
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#response').fadeIn(300, function(){ $(this).html(response.confirm); });
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#response').fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).empty();});
            }, 5000);
        },
    });*/
});
```

The whole JS is in `jQuery(document).ready(function($){}` included.

At the beginning, I thought it was a problem with WP Ajax, but then I saw that the variable "task_content" wasn't posted at all in fact, nothing appears in console, except for "task_due" value.

Is that any typo I can't see?

I cloned JS and HTML from another page of my app, which is working perfectly. I can't understand where the problem is!

## **EDIT:**

The HTML is included in a dialog window, a modal similar to Bootstrap's one.

So I changed the button like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="createNewTask('<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>');" id="new_task" class="button-helpy"><?php _e( 'Confirm', 'helpy'); ?></button>
```

And the JS function:

```
function createNewTask(id) {
var task_due = jQuery('#new_task_due').val();
var task_content = jQuery('#new_task_content').val();
console.log(task_content);
console.log(task_due);
/* var data = {
    action: 'project_request',
    task_content: task_content,
    task_due: task_due,
    id: id,
    todo: 'task',
};

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {
        jQuery('#response').fadeIn(300, function(){ jQuery(this).html(response.confirm); });
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('#response').fadeOut(300, function(){ jQuery(this).empty();});
        }, 5000);
    },
});*/
```

}

Result is the same :(

Comment: is there any js conflict in the console?

Comment: Nothing at all!

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: I really don't know. This is the kind of errors that burns my brain! :)

Comment: @Banzay tried with on() also but nothing

Comment: can you share your website URL?

Comment: I'm working local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying almost everything, I decided to insert the textarea in a bootstrap modal.

Somehow, the js code of the old dialog blocked the value reading. I didn't figured out why and which part of it, but the problem was definitely there.

Thanks to all for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's failing for you, here's the fiddle working properly: https://jsfiddle.net/py5scvhm/

BTW instead of `.live()` use `.on()` as `.live()` is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: With on() I get nothing, not even the date.

Comment: Check the fiddle.. try adding random date and value.. it should work!

Comment: I marked your question because you told me to change from live() to on()

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
$('#new_task_content').val();
```

Try getting value using

```
$('textarea#new_task_content').val();
```

Also debug in console & check what object is

```
$('#new_task_content')
```

Comment: Tried also with textarea before the id, same result.

Comment: Debug: a.fn.init[1]
0
:
textarea#new_task_content.helpy-textarea
context
:
document
length
:
1
selector
:
"#new_task_content"
__proto__
:
Object[0]

Comment: You are fetching an ID and that's going to be unique all over the document. no need to use `$(textarea#new_task_content)`

Comment: Why downVote? I asked to try assuming that there can be 2 same ids for different elements.

Comment: No @DineshRS, there's nothing with the same id, this is the first thing I've checked. Of course your comment seems right to me, it can happen to give the same IDs to different elements.